# Load and evaluate file from .emacs

Tags: emacs, repository

I work on many different machines and VMs, each of which might have their own needs regarding options for `.emacs`.  I have a Git repository / subdirectory `.common-system` with a second Emacs Lisp file `.common-system/emacs` containing common definitions used for all my systems.

What changes can I make to `.emacs` which will load and `eval` my secondary definition file automagically?  Bonus points for keeping the secondary file out of my buffer list after startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
(load-file ".common-system/emacs")
```

It works better (as [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283394/stefan) suggests) if you specify the full path to the file, something like

```
(load-file "~/.common-system/emacs")
```

Comment: I'd recommend `(load "~/.common-system/emacs")` instead, tho the difference is very minor.

Comment: @Stefan, what is exactly the difference?

Comment: @user273158 Stefan's suggestion loads the file relative to your home directory, whereas mine loads it relative to where you started Emacs (unless you're doing something else to change the current directory).  It's good advice - I left it out because you didn't specify where `.common-system` lived.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: For nitpickers: there's another difference, which is that it saves you 5 characters ;-).  `load`, `load-file`, and `load-library` are basically all identical: `load` is the actual *function*, while `load-file` and `load-library` are two *commands* that provide access to it interactively with slightly different defaults and completion behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with you current repository layout, using `load-file` (as suggested by others) is the way to go.

However, if you name your top-level directory `.emacs.d` and place the file `init.el` in it, Emacs will find it and run it automatically. That way, you don't have to hand-edit a `.emacs` file on each system you use.

Answer (score 0):

You use a (cond), dispatching on variables such as user-login-name, system-type and system-name

```
(cond
  ((equal user-login-name 
          "myname")
   ;; Stuff
   )
  ((equal system-type 'gnu/linux)
   (require 'some-file)
   ;; some-file, could be any file in load-path, named some-file.el, and ending
   ;; with (provide 'some-file)
   ))
```